# how to go next line in ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

hey guys i wanna to load a File path in my listBox.
everything is ok 
i just have a problem that is when i Close the app and then open it again
loaded files are in the one lane and it recognize them as one item in listBox
i tried to use "\n" , "\r" none of these works...
so what u guys suggest?
(i save user changes in App Setting to read them later)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Properties.Settings.Default.FileList != string.Empty)
    {
        fileListBox.Items.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.FileList);
    }
    UnlockForm f2 = new UnlockForm();

    if (Properties.Settings.Default.PasswordCheck == true)
        f2.ShowDialog();
    else
        return;
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    op = new OpenFileDialog();
    op.Title = "Select your stuff";
    op.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileName = op.FileName;
        fileListBox.Items.Add(fileName);
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.FileList += fileName+"\n";
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: You're adding a string that's why only one line, split on a delimiter or use a List<T> in your app settings then use AddRange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the property in settings designer:

- Set the name to whatever you want, for example `Files`
- Set the type as `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`
- Set the scope as `User`
- If you want to have some default values, use <kbd>...</kbd> in `Value` cell to edit default value.

Then you can easily set it as `DataSource` of the `ListBox`.

```
listBox1.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.Files;
```

Also to add some values:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Files.Add("something");
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

If you added something to the `Files`, if you want the `ListBox` shows the changes, set `DataSource` to null and then to `Files` again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have defined your FileList as String in our App Settings. There are two ways you can approach this.

a) Using FileList as Collection.

You can change the Type of FileList to StringCollection in your App Settings. Then, you can add items to your list as follows

```
 fileListBox.Items.AddRange(Properties.Settings.Default.FileList.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

b) Using FileList as String.

If you really want to retain Properties.Settings.Default.FileList as string, you would need to split it on the run using your delimiter character (let's say ';')

```
fileListBox.Items.AddRange(Properties.Settings.Default.FileList.Split(new[] { ';' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

In your case, a collection might be a better approach unless you have specific reasons outside the scope of OP to use string.